# Sharing preferences between an Activity and a Service

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1, sharedpreferences

I have an .apk that has a `Service` and an `Activity` that I want to share preferences. I guess I use `getSharedPreferences("somename", MODE_PRIVATE)` to do that. A couple of questions though:

1. Is `MODE_PRIVATE` OK?  Does that mean it's private for the application or the Activity/Service?
2. I have a `PreferenceActivity`. How do I tell it to manage "somename" instead of the default preferences?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MODE_PRIVATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE) : File creation mode: the default mode, where the created file can only be accessed by the calling application (or all applications sharing the same user ID). So, MODE_PRIVATE is ok.

To share preferences between activity and service all you need is to use application context to access(read and write) the preferences, not activity or service context.

Comment: Application `Context` won't work unless both your `Activity` and `Service` are running on the same process.